# What causes the disturbances in fields that produce electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I know that electromagnetic radiation is synchronized by oscillations of electric and magnetic fields, but what causes the disturbance in the fields to create the waves in the first place?

Comment: Moving charges.

Comment: Nope. **Accelerating** charges. A changing dipole moment. A changing monopole moment is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Classically speaking, electromagnetic radiation **is** an oscillation of electric and magnetic fields which propagates.

The acceleration of charged particles causes those oscillations - the motion of charges and the electric and magnetic fields are coupled - see [Maxwell's equations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/maxeq.html).

For example, an antenna broadcasts electromagnetic radiation when an alternating current flows in the conductor of the antenna; i.e. when charges move inside the antenna.

Comment: The *acceleration* of charges.

Comment: Good clarification - editing...

Answer (score 1):

There are several mechanisms to create/cause electromagnetic waves:

- Macroscopically: **accelerating charge** (just moving at constant velocity is not enough; this is why we drive antennae with an *alternating* current pushing electrons back and forth.)
- Microscopically: **spontaneous (i.e. without cause)**; think of exicted atoms emitting a photon. This is what happens in phosphorous materials that you shone light on.
- Microscopically: **stimulated** by an already present wave; this is what happens in a laser when a photon causes an excited atom to emit another photon

There are likely other mechanisms that my physicist colleagues will enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that what you call *disturbances in the fields*, are the *oscillations of electric and magnetic fields* that you mention just before. (Well, these disturbances ***propagate***. The solution of the Maxwell's equation are ***traveling fields***. Let me for top simplicity the case without charges (the case with charges are covered in my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166856/magnetic-field-due-to-a-charge-having-uniform-velocity/167004#167004), and also in the answer to a [former question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166888/the-propagation-of-electric-field).

So, starting with the [Maxwell equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Conventional_formulation_in_SI_units)

$$\frac {\partial \vec B}{\partial t} = -\nabla \times \vec E , \tag{i}$$

$$\frac {\partial \vec E}{\partial t} = \frac {1}{\epsilon_0 \mu_0} \nabla \times \vec B , \tag{ii}$$

where we know that $1/(\epsilon_0 \mu_0) = c^2$. By the time-derivation of the equation $\text {(ii)}$ and then introducing $\text {(i)}$,

$$\frac {\partial ^2\vec E}{\partial ^2 t} = -c^2 \nabla \times \left(\nabla \times \vec E , \right) \tag{iii}$$

We know how to deal with the twice $\nabla$,

$$\frac {\partial ^2\vec E}{\partial ^2 t} = c^2 \left(\nabla ^2 \vec E - \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec E) \right)$$

But, since we supposed that there are no charges, and by Maxwell's equation $(\nabla \cdot \vec E) = \rho / \epsilon_0$, the 2nd term in the RHS is zero. So we het a homogeneous equation, which is the wave-equation,

$$\frac {\partial ^2\vec E}{\partial ^2 t} - c^2 \nabla ^2 \vec E = 0, \tag{iv}$$

whose solution is of the form

$$vec E = \vec E_1 e^{i(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)} + \vec E_2 e^{-i(\vec k \cdot \vec r + \omega t)}. \tag{v}$$,

So, we got traveling waves.